# How does the V8 toString(radix) method in Google Chrome or in Node.js handle floating point numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

The method works clearly with integer numbers, e.g.

```js
(25).toString(2)
= '11001'

(25).toString(16)
= '19'

(25).toString(36)
= 'p'
```

But entering floats results in

```js
(0.1).toString(2)
= '0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101'

(0.1).toString(16)
= '0.1999999999999a'

(0.1).toString(36)
= '0.3lllllllllm'
```

V8 is said to be an open-source engine. However, I cannot find the exact implementation of this method in the repository in order to understand it. How does the function handle floats?

Comment: see: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/src/numbers/conversions.cc (you can 'find' tostring)

Comment: Thank you for the link. Entering 'tostring' does not perfectly matches and leads to the test in line 1478. Do you mean that `DoubleToRadixCString` (starting by line 1314) is used in the case of my examples?

Comment: makes sense, I only gave it a cursory glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

@pilchard's link is right; more specifically the function you're looking for is [DoubleToRadixCString](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/src/numbers/conversions.cc#L1357).

The observation that 0.1 (decimal) is a non-terminating fraction in its binary representation (which is, of course, how doubles are stored inside computers) is a nice illustration of the underlying reason why `0.1 * 3 == 0.30000000000000004`: the non-terminating fractions are necessarily cut off at some point, which constitutes a rounding error, and some operations make these rounding errors visible. It's the binary equivalent of a similar effect in decimal: when you represent 1/3 as "0.333333" (arbitrarily choosing 6 digits as the represented length, but if you only cut off after 100 digits that wouldn't really change anything), and multiply that by 3, you get "0.999999", not 1.

Comment: thank you! :) Short question: what `base::Double(integer / radix).Exponent()` and especially `Exponent()` in the line 1419 mean?

Comment: It's a call to this function: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/src/base/numbers/double.h;l=76;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=v8::base::Double::Exponent